# Removing duplicates in a string in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

What is an efficient algorithm to removing all duplicates in a string?

For example : **aaaabbbccdbdbcd**

Required result: **abcd**

Comment: Do you need to maintain / impose order on the result?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You use a hashtable to store currently discovered keys (access O(1)) and then loop through the array. If a character is in the hashtable, discard it. If it isn't add it to the hashtable and a result string.

Overall: O(n) time (and space).

The naive solution is to search for the character is the result string as you process each one. That O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: +1, Or if they have accss to it HashSet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495294.aspx

Comment: If you have a large string compared the possible # vakues of the characters (eg like if it is ASCII), you might use a =n array of bools instead on a hashtable

Comment: The best case to retrieve a value from hashtable is O(1) and the worst case O(n). The overall worst case complexity for the algorithm is O(n^2).

Comment: that is irrelavent in this case as you by definition of the algo have either 0 or 1 item for each hash key

Comment: @jk The hashtable has always 0 or 1 entries for a key. The worst case O(n) is that all n values are in one bucket.

Comment: @Thomas Jung: For this problem computing a Perfect Hashing function is easy (typically the ASCII or at worst the Unicode Code Point value) therefore you perform access in `O(1)`.

Comment: @Matthieu Not Exactly. Suppose you have perfect hash function from char -> 2 byte Int. This is easy. Now your Hashtable size is smaller than 2^16. Say 15. When you enter 2 values it is quite probable that you will have a collision (1/15 for the second value). The index is some complicated version of idx = hash % size. If you want absolutely no collisions you have to create a hashtable of size 2^16.

Comment: @Matthieu I've realized that I've cut corners a bit. You can of course create a perfect hash function for hashtables with size < 2^16. Cuckoo hashing has for example O(1) worst case access complexity but worst case O(n) for puts. I suppose there is no hashtable that has worst case complexity of O(1) for all operations.

Comment: It depends on the input size: if you can manage to have an upper-bound for the size of a bucket, then you can always pretend to be `O(1)` even though it could be daunting :x Here it seems easy enough for ASCII charachters (256 of them) and of course a bit more difficult if you wish to take all the Unicode Points into account, yet with a sufficiently big bitset you could have good performance without too much memory (server-scale)

Answer (score 5):

In **Python**

```
>>> ''.join(set("aaaabbbccdbdbcd"))
'acbd'
```

If the order needs to be preserved

```
>>> q="aaaabbbccdbdbcd"                    # this one is not
>>> ''.join(sorted(set(q),key=q.index))    # so efficient
'abcd'
```

or

```
>>> S=set()
>>> res=""
>>> for c in "aaaabbbccdbdbcd":
...  if c not in S:
...   res+=c
...   S.add(c)
... 
>>> res
'abcd'
```

or

```
>>> S=set()
>>> L=[]
>>> for c in "aaaabbbccdbdbcd":
...  if c not in S:
...   L.append(c)
...   S.add(c)
... 
>>> ''.join(L)
'abcd'
```

In **python3.1**

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> ''.join(list(OrderedDict((c,0) for c in "aaaabbbccdbdbcd").keys()))
'abcd'
```

Comment: I knew set would be awesome for this, but I'm new to python and was trying to figure out how to join them while you posted this... Now I know!

Comment: @recursive, I added some order preserving options

Answer (score 5):

This closely related to the question: [Detecting repetition with infinite input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279568/detecting-repetition-with-infinite-input).

The hashtable approach may not be optimal depending on your input. **Hashtables have a certain amount of overhead** (buckets, entry objects). It is huge overhead compared to the actual stored char. (If you target environment is Java it is even worse as the HashMap is of type `Map<Character,?>`.) The worse case runtime for a Hashtable access is O(n) due to collisions.

You need only **8kb** too represent all 2-byte unicode characters in a plain **BitSet**. This may be optimized if your input character set is more restricted or by using a compressed BitSets (as long as you have a sparse  BitSet). The runtime performance will be favorable for a BitSet it is O(1).

Comment: I am afraid to mention that you are mixing (somehow) concepts and implementations. I view the fact that you are using a `BitSet` to implement your own `HashTable` as a proof that the `HashTable` is a perfectly viable solution.

Comment: @Matthieu Using a Hashtable or a BitSet has certain trade-offs. The hashtable works best for small sets of characters. The BitSet works best when the number of characters is large or can be restricted to a known range. A BitSet is not a Hashtable. The Hashtable here is used as a Set as someone mentioned. The BitSet is used analogous. If you can replace one with the other does not mean that they are equally good solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Keep an array of 256 "seen" booleans, one for each possible character.
Stream your string. If you haven't seen the character before, output it and set the "seen" flag for that character.

Comment: It has not been told what coding is used, though

Answer (score 2):

PHP algorythm - O(n):

```php
function remove_duplicate_chars($str) {
    if (2 > $len = strlen($str)) {
        return $str;
    }
    $flags = array_fill(0,256,false);
    $flags[ord($str[0])]=true;
    $j = 1;
    for ($i=1; $i<$len; $i++) {
        $ord = ord($str[$i]);
        if (!$flags[$ord]) {
            $str[$j] = $str[$i];
            $j++;
            $flags[$ord] = true;
        }
    }
    if ($j<$i) { //if duplicates removed
        $str = substr($str,0,$j);
    }
    return $str;
}

echo remove_duplicate_chars('aaaabbbccdbdbcd'); // result: 'abcd'
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can Do this in O(n) only if you are using HashTable. Code is given below 
Please Note- It is assumed that number of possible characters in input string are 
256

```
void removeDuplicates(char *str)
{
 int len = strlen(str); //Gets the length of the String
 int count[256] = {0};  //initializes all elements as zero
 int i;
     for(i=0;i<len;i++)
     {
        count[str[i]]++;  
        if(count[str[i]] == 1)
          printf("%c",str[i]);                  
     }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#define MAX_SIZE 256

int main()
{
    bool arr[MAX_SIZE] = {false};

    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        while(arr[s[i]] == true && i < s.length())
        {
            i++;
        }
        if(i < s.length())
        {
            s[k]    = s[i];
            arr[s[k]] = true;
            k++;
        }
    }
    s.resize(k);

    cout << s<< endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the `arr[s[i]] == true` mean?

Comment: Just having arr[s[i]] there would do too. Is that what you meant?

Comment: `arr[s[i]]` is what I'm interested in - do I understand correctly that you use `char` (which is an `int`) to index the array?

Comment: Yes, that's right and it should work. What's the issue with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
  string newString = new string("aaaaabbbbccccdddddd".ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray());
```

or

```
 char[] characters = "aaaabbbccddd".ToCharArray();
                string result = string.Empty ;
                foreach (char c in characters)
                {
                    if (result.IndexOf(c) < 0)
                        result += c.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: O(n^2) isn't very efficient... (once the data set gets big enough). For small strings this is probably faster than a hashset based lookup though

Comment: i agree , what about the new one ?

Comment: String concatenation in a loop will be slower than the searching of the character within the string...

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you'd probably use an `std::set`:

```
std::string input("aaaabbbccddd");
std::set<char> unique_chars(input.begin(), input.end());
```

In theory you could use `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::set`, which should give O(N)  expected overall complexity (though O(N<sup>2</sup>) worst case), where this one is O(N lg M) (where N=number of total characters, M=number of unique characters). Unless you have long strings with a *lot* of unique characters, this version will probably be faster though.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the string and then remove the duplicate characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "aaaabbbccdbdbcd";

    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    s.erase(std::unique(s.begin(), s.end()), s.end());

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use for automata.

Answer (score 0):

C++ - O(n) time, O(1) space, and the output is sorted.

```
std::string characters = "aaaabbbccddd";
std::vector<bool> seen(std::numeric_limits<char>::max()-std::numeric_limits<char>::min());

for(std::string::iterator it = characters.begin(), endIt = characters.end(); it != endIt; ++it) {
  seen[(*it)-std::numeric_limits<char>::min()] = true;
}

characters = "";
for(char ch = std::numeric_limits<char>::min(); ch != std::numeric_limits<char>::max(); ++ch) {
  if( seen[ch-std::numeric_limits<char>::min()] ) {
    characters += ch;
  }
}
```

Comment: O(1) space??? I see a vector of bools.. Isnt is same as an array of bools of 256 characters??

Comment: @smartmuki: It's O(1) space because the size of the `vector<bool>` does not vary according to the size of the input - it's 256 bools no matter what the input is.

Answer (score 0):

in C this is how i did it: O(n) in time since we only have one for loop.

```
void remDup(char *str)
{
    int flags[256] = { 0 };

    for(int i=0; i<(int)strlen(str); i++) {
        if( flags[str[i]] == 0 )
            printf("%c", str[i]);

        flags[str[i]] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class RemoveDup {

    public static String Duplicate()
    {
        HashSet h = new HashSet();
        String value = new String("aaaabbbccdbdbcd");
        String finalString = new String();
        int stringLength = value.length();
        for (int i=0;i<=stringLength-1;i++)
        {
            if(h.add(value.charAt(i)))
            {
                finalString = finalString + (value.charAt(i));
            }


        }
        return finalString;

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println(Duplicate());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get a list of first 26 prime numbers..
Now you can map each character (a,b,c,d etc) to each prime number.. (alphabetically say a=2, b=3, c=5 etc.. or depending upon relative abundance of the characters like most frequently used letter with lower prime say e=2, r=3, a=5 etc)...store that mapping in an integer array
int prime[26]..

iterate through all the characters of the string

```
i=0;
int product = 1;
while(char[i] != null){
   if(product % prime[i] == 0)
      the character is already present delete it
   else
      product = product*prime[i];
}
```

this algorithm will work in O(n) time.. with O(1) space requirement
It will work well when number of distinct character are less in the string... other wise product will exceed "int" range and we have to handle that case properly

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()    
{    
    std::string s = "aaacabbbccdbdbcd";

    std::set<char> set1;
    set1.insert(s.begin(), s.end());

    for(set<char>::iterator it = set1.begin(); it!= set1.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it;

    return 0;
}

std::set takes O(log n) to insert
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n) solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void removeDuplicates(char *);

void removeDuplicates(char *inp)
{
        int i=0, j=0, FLAG=0, repeat=0;

     while(inp[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(FLAG==1)
        {
                inp[i-repeat]=inp[i];
        }
        if(j==(j | 1<<(inp[i]-'\0')))
        {
                repeat++;
                FLAG=1;
        }
                j= j | 1<<(inp[i]-'\0');
                i++;
    }

     inp[i-repeat]='\0';
}

int main()
{
     char inp[100] = "aaAABCCDdefgccc";
    //char inp[100] = "ccccc";
    //char inp[100] = "\0";
    //char *inp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

    printf (" INPUT STRING : %s\n", inp);

     removeDuplicates(inp);

    printf (" OUTPUT STRING : %s:\n", inp);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the use of built in Python functions are more efficient that those "self made". Like this:

=====================

NOTE: maintain order

**CODE**

```
string = "aaabbbccc"

product = reduce((lambda x,y: x if (y in x) else x+y), string)

print product
```

**OUTPUT**

```
abc
```

=========================

NOTE: order neglected

**CODE**

```
string = "aaabssabcdsdwa"

str_uniq = ''.join(set(string))

print str_uniq
```

**OUTPUT**

```
acbdsw
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# by using python
def cleantext(word):
    if(len(word)==1):

        return word
    if word[0]==word[1]:

        return cleantext(word[1:])

return word[0]+ cleantext(word[1:])
print(cleantext(word))
```